# Conditional selection of elements of a list in Base R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, lapply

I'm trying to find the unique elements in the variables `list`ed as `x`.

The only *constraint* is that I want to first find the variable (here either `a`, `b`, or `c`) in the list whose `max` element is smallest, and keep that variable untouched at the top of the output?

I have tried something but can't implement the *constraint* above:

**P.S.** My goal is to achieve a function/looping structure to handle larger lists.

```
x = list(a = 1:5, b = 3:7, c = 6:9)  ## a list of 3 variables; variable `a` has the smallest 
                                     ## max among all variables in the list, so keep `a`
                                     ## untouched at the top of the output.

x[-1] <- Map(setdiff, x[-1], x[-length(x)]) ## Now, take the values of `b` not shared 
                                            ## with `a`, AND values of `c` not shared   
                                            ## with `b`.

x   

 # Output:                     # This output is OK now, but if we change order of `a`, `b`, 
                               # and `c` in the initial list the output will change.
                               # This is why the constraint above is necessary?
 $a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$b
[1] 6 7

$c
[1] 8 9
```

Comment: Suppose that `c` had the smallest max. Then in the output, would you compare the values of `a` with `c` (at the top)? Or does `c` go to the top after this elimination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Find which element in the list has smallest max. 
smallest_max <- which.min(sapply(x, max))

#Rearrange the list by keeping the smallest max in first place 
#followed by remaining ones
new_x <- c(x[smallest_max], x[-smallest_max])

#Apply the Map function
new_x[-1] <- Map(setdiff, new_x[-1], new_x[-length(new_x)])

new_x
#$a
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

#$b
#[1] 6 7

#$c
#[1] 8 9
```

---

We can wrap this up in a function and then use it

```
keep_smallest_max <- function(x) {
   smallest_max <- which.min(sapply(x, max))
   new_x <- c(x[smallest_max], x[-smallest_max])
   new_x[-1] <- Map(setdiff, new_x[-1], new_x[-length(new_x)])
   new_x
}

keep_smallest_max(x)
#$a
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

#$b
#[1] 6 7

#$c
#[1] 8 9
```